# is there a way to directly pass latex code to before_body in an rmarkdown YAML header?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr, bookdown

For example, Is there a way to pass `\newpage` to the `before_body:` YAML tag, without having to use and pass a separate .tex file?

i.e. something like this:

```
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    toc: yes
    includes:
      before_body: "\newpage"
```

instead of this:

```
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    toc: yes
    includes:
      before_body: before_body.tex
```

where `before_body.tex` contains `\newpage`

Thanks !

Comment: I'd love that feature, too (disclaimer: I'm one of the main authors of bookdown and rmarkdown :). Sometimes I feel it's awkward to have to create another file, because it makes the Rmd document not self-contained. Anyway, this is not possible for now. The only way that I can think of is: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/eng-cat.html but you probably won't like this solution.

Comment: @YihuiXie, That's exactly how I feel! Haha. Being able to move an rmarkdown template around without worrying about separate dependencies would just feel great. Thanks for confirming though, I'll leave the question open for a few more days just in case there are any other janky -but easy- solutions :P